# Не выполняется кнопка в телеграм боте на Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот

Создал 2-х уровневую клавиатуру бота. В главном меню все кнопки работают, а в меню О проекте не работают кнопки, тобиж отклика бота на них не происходит.

```
import config
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

# Клавиатура главного меню
keyboard1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Расписание ')
item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Программы ')
item3 = types.KeyboardButton('О проекте  ')
keyboard1.add(item1, item2)
keyboard1.add(item3)
# Клавиатура раздела "О проекте"
keyboard2 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
item4 = types.KeyboardButton(' Поддержать проект ')
item5 = types.KeyboardButton('Назад')
keyboard2.add(item4, item5)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Альфа версия BSUT Helper. Разработчик @mikitos59', reply_markup=keyboard1)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text == 'О проекте  ':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Альфа версия BSUT Helper. Разработчик @mikitos59', reply_markup=keyboard2)
    elif message.text == 'Программы ':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Здесь будет отображаться список програм для скачивания')
    elif message.text == 'Расписание ':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Здесь будет отображаться расписание занятий')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text == 'Назад':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы вышли в главное меню', reply_markup=keyboard1)


bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хэндлеры работают так, что проходят по условиям сверху вниз. Если условие подошло, то обработчик идёт внутрь хендлера и выполняет указанный алгоритм. Остальные хэндлеры не исполняются.

#### Как работает ваш код:

Пользователь нажал кнопку "Назад"

`@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])`

В сообщении должна быть команда /start. Условие не выполнено, идём дальше.

`@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])`

Сообщение должно быть текстовым. Условие выполнено, **идём внутрь**. Внутри текст не подходит ни под одно из указанных условий (if, elif), поэтому обработка сообщения успешно завершается без действий.

### Как исправить

Сделайте отдельные хэндлеры для каждого сообщения, в условиях укажите ожидаемый текст.

Можно и в одном хэндлере ловить целый блок кнопок, но для этого понадобится перейти с устаревшего `telebot` на [aiogram](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/), где реализована система FSM (если коротко - пользователю назначается состояния "жду кнопку из меню 2", можно одним хэндлеров ловить всё, что пользователь в этом состоянии напишет).

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ! Поместите строку

```
if message.text == 'Назад':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы вышли в главное меню', reply_markup=keyboard1)
```

В таб со всеми if и elif, сменив if на elif, то есть вы должны их совместить и получить:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text == 'О проекте  ':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Альфа версия BSUT Helper. Разработчик @mikitos59', reply_markup=keyboard2)
    elif message.text == 'Программы ':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Здесь будет отображаться список програм для скачивания')
    elif message.text == 'Расписание ':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Здесь будет отображаться расписание занятий')
    elif message.text == 'Назад':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы вышли в главное меню', reply_markup=keyboard1)
```